# Array of structures passed as parameter is not reflecting changes

Tags: arrays, struct

Today I was working with my lab assignment of finding closest pair of points in C language.
I know pretty well how to send array of structures to function but for some reason the array is not reflecting its changes in main() function.
Since my code was quite messy I created a smaller code to understand the fault.
Following is the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int x;
    int y;
};

void fun(struct node *);

int main()
{
    struct node *arr = (struct node *)malloc(2 * sizeof(struct node));
    arr[0].x = 1;
    arr[0].y = 2;
    printf("%d %d\n", arr[0].x, arr[0].y);
    fun(arr);
    printf("%d %d\n", arr[0].x, arr[0].y);

    return 0;
}

struct node *fun2()
{
    struct node *tmp = (struct node *)malloc(2 * sizeof(struct node));
    tmp[0].x = 3;
    tmp[0].y = 4;

    return tmp;
}

void fun(struct node *arr)
{
    arr = fun2();
}
```

Output

```
1 2
1 2
```

but for the following code arr array reflects changes

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int x;
    int y;
};

void fun(struct node *);

int main()
{
    struct node *arr = (struct node *)malloc(2 * sizeof(struct node));
    arr[0].x = 1;
    arr[0].y = 2;
    printf("%d %d\n", arr[0].x, arr[0].y);
    fun(arr);
    printf("%d %d\n", arr[0].x, arr[0].y);

    return 0;
}

struct node *fun2()
{
    struct node *tmp = (struct node *)malloc(2 * sizeof(struct node));
    tmp[0].x = 3;
    tmp[0].y = 4;

    return tmp;
}

void fun(struct node *arr)
{
//    arr = fun2();
    arr[0].x = 3;
    arr[0].y = 4;
}
```

Output

```
1 2
3 4
```

Could anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first version, `fun` is assigning to the parameter `arr`, which doesn't change the argument `arr` in `main`.  In your second, you are making changes to what `arr` points to: the structures you wish to change.

Comment: I just understood it. Since arr in main() and arr in fun() are pointing to same memory location in version2 hence it is not changing while in version 1 arr in fun() is changing its pointed memory location to somewhere else. It was so stupid of me. Thanks for your reply.